# Spring MVC passing object to JSP and back

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I've controller class where I initialize method where I am adding list of string to model and view.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my-site", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doStuff(HttpServletRequest request){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("do-stuff");
        ...

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "cba");
    modelAndView.addObject("myList", list);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Question number 1: How do I access my list in jsp file and use it later in java script?
I am trying something like:

```
var myList = [];
<c:forEach var="entry" items="'${myList}'">
        myList.push("${entry}");
    </c:forEach>
```

But for some reason inside myList object instead of having two elements: "abc" and "cba" I have "[abc", " cba]" which contains extra symbols. Why? What I am doing wrong and how do I fix this issue?

Question number 2: I have the input button.

```
<input type="button" id="executeBtn" name="executeBtn" value="Execute">
```

I want on this button click fire the event and send `myList` object back to controller. 
Could you please provide example method of JS side and Controller's method.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Why is your `${myList}` EL expression quoted? Get rid of the single quotes

```
var myList = [];
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${myList}">
    myList.push("${entry}");
</c:forEach>
```

> I want on this button click fire the event and send myList object back
>   to controller

The `myList` no longer exists in Java form. It exists as a serialized format in your `myList` var object. You'll need to serialize it to a format that your web application can understand: a form object, comma separated list, JSON, XML, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please point me or provide an example how to manipulate `myList` on JS side. and how to send updated object back to controller. Thanks!